# How to run the "Purge" command through NSTask?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, bash, nstask

I'm making a free Mac app that is simply a wrapper over the "purge" command that can be run in Terminal.  I'm tired of the ripoffs that are populating the Mac App Store and I just want to help people.  I've got the GUI finished I just can't figure out how to run the command successfully.

I know I need to use `NSTask`, but I'm probably not doing it correctly.

```
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/bin/sh"];
[task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Purge", nil]];
[task launch];
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `purge` executable is in `/usr/bin`, so:

```
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/purge"];
[task launch];
```

or, even easier:

```
[NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/purge" arguments:[NSArray array]];
```

Comment: Thanks!  Worked like a charm.

Comment: it says launch path is not accessible looks like I need to run it as  su , but can I somehow make it programatically ?
(Xcode5.1 osx maveriks)